# Is the image of a `hcomp` the `hcomp` of images?

Tags: agda, continuous, cubical-type-theory

I am trying to fill the remaining one hole in the following program:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}
module _ where

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Cubical.Foundations.Everything

data S1 : Type where
  base : S1
  loop : base ≡ base

data NS : Type where
  N : NS
  S : NS
  W : S ≡ N
  E : N ≡ S

module _ where
  open Iso

  NS-Iso : Iso NS S1
  NS-Iso .fun N = base
  NS-Iso .fun S = base
  NS-Iso .fun (W i) = base
  NS-Iso .fun (E i) = loop i
  NS-Iso .inv base = N
  NS-Iso .inv (loop i) = (E ∙ W) i
  NS-Iso .leftInv N = refl
  NS-Iso .leftInv S = sym W
  NS-Iso .leftInv (W i) = λ j → W (i ∨ ~ j)
  NS-Iso .leftInv (E i) = λ j → compPath-filler E W (~ j) i
  NS-Iso .rightInv base = refl
  NS-Iso .rightInv (loop i) = ?
```

The type of the hole is:

```
fun NS-Iso (inv NS-Iso (loop i)) ≡ loop i
```

`inv NS-Iso (loop i)` of course definitionally equal to `(E ∙ W) i`, but what is then `fun NS-Iso ((E ∙ W) i)`? Is there some kind of homomorphism / continuity / similar property with which I can use the definitions of `fun NS-Iso (E i)` and `fun NS-Iso (W i)` to figure out what it is?

Since `fun NS-Iso (E i) = loop i` and `fun NS-Iso (W i) = base`, I thought this might be a valid filling (pun intended) of the hole:

```
  NS-Iso .rightInv (loop i) = λ j → compPath-filler loop (refl {x = base}) (~ j) i
```

But that gives a type error:

```
hcomp (doubleComp-faces (λ _ → base) (λ _ → base) i) (loop i) 
!=
fun NS-Iso (hcomp (doubleComp-faces (λ _ → N) W i) (E i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the answer is, basically, yes!

Let's add a local binding of our goal in `NS-Iso .rightInv (loop i)` just to keep an eye on the type:

```
  NS-Iso .rightInv (loop i) = goal
    where
      goal : (fun NS-Iso ∘ inv NS-Iso) (loop i) ≡ loop i
      goal = ?
```

Since we have

```
  NS-Iso .inv (loop i) = (E ∙ W) i
```

the type of `goal` reduces to:

```
      step1 : fun NS-Iso ((E ∙ W) i) ≡ loop i
```

And now comes the crucial step, the actual answer to my question: **can we push in `fun NS-Iso` into `E ∙ W`?**

Let's draw wavy lines between the points and paths where `fun NS-Iso` is directly defined, or where we know its value by `cong _ refl = refl`:

```
      base                                   base
        ^  ~                                ~  ^
        |     ~                          ~     |
        |        ~                    ~        |
        |          N                N          |
        |          ^                ^          |
   refl | ~~~ refl |                |  W ~~~~~ | refl
        |          |                |          |
        |          N -------------> S          |
        |        ~         E          ~        |
        |     ~            ~             ~     |
        |  ~               ~                ~  |
      base --------------------------------> base
                         loop
```

`E ∙ W` is the lid of the inner box, and it turns out **yes, its image by `fun NS-Iso` is indeed the lid of the outer box**:

```
      step2 : (cong (fun NS-Iso) E ∙ (cong (fun NS-Iso) W)) i ≡ loop i
```

In graphical form:

```
                           ?
      base - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - > base
        ^  ~                                ~  ^
        |     ~                          ~     |
        |        ~        E ∙ W       ~        |
        |          N - - - - - - -> N          |
        |          ^                ^          |
   refl | ~~~ refl |                |  W ~~~~~ | refl
        |          |                |          |
        |          N -------------> S          |
        |        ~         E          ~        |
        |     ~            ~             ~     |
        |  ~               ~                ~  |
      base -------------------------------> base
                         loop
```

So we can reduce the `fun NS-Iso` applications now:

```
      step3 : (loop ∙ (λ _ → base)) i ≡ loop i
```

which we can finally solve with a library function `doubleCompPath-filler`.

The complete code:

```
  NS-Iso .rightInv (loop i) = goal
    where
      step3 : (loop ∙ (λ _ → base)) i ≡ loop i
      step3 = cong (λ p → p i) (symP (ompPath-filler loop (λ _ → base)))

      step2 : (cong (fun NS-Iso) E ∙ (cong (fun NS-Iso) W)) i ≡ loop i
      step2 = step3

      step1 : fun NS-Iso ((E ∙ W) i) ≡ loop i
      step1 j = step2 j

      goal : (fun NS-Iso ∘ inv NS-Iso) (loop i) ≡ loop i
      goal j = step1 j
```

I don't know why I needed to eta-expand `goal` and `step1`, but otherwise Agda doesn't recognize that they meet the boundary conditions.